# Read gzip from pubsub notification in dataflow

Tags: python, gzip, pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow job that pulls messages from a pubsub subscription containing the path of gzip files on gcs.
The job decompress file in streaming mode, validate each record of the file and push them to different topics (valid or dlq).
The gzip uncompression and iteration for each file is very slow and blocking the pipeline. I was expecting that, for each row, the next ParDo started.
Pipeline code is:

```
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from google.api_core.exceptions import NotFound
from google.cloud.pubsub import SchemaServiceClient
from utils.utils import beam, logging, filter_entity, filter_subfolder, \
    extract_message_data, EncodeMessage, CopyFile, ValidateRecord, log_stacktrace, FILE_EXTENSION, ExtractFn, LogFn, PublishToPubSubEncoded
from utils.pipeline_options import IngestionPodOptions


def create_pipeline_option_from_configs(pipeline_options: PipelineOptions, path_conf_test: str):
    with open(f'{path_conf_test}/{pipeline_options.configuration_json_file}', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        entities = data['entities']
        configs = data['job-configs']
        project = configs['project']

    if pipeline_options.configuration_json_file == 'configuration-local.json' or pipeline_options.configuration_json_file == 'configuration-component-test.json':
        with_attributes = False
        options = PipelineOptions(
            project=configs['project'],
            streaming=configs['streaming'],
            job_name=configs['job_name'],
            staging_location=configs['staging_location'],
            temp_location=configs['temp_location'],
            region=configs['region'],
            save_main_session=configs['save_main_session'],
            max_num_workers=configs['max_num_workers'],
            setup_file=configs['setup_file'],
            service_account_email=configs['service_account_email'],
            sdk_container_image=configs['sdk_container_image'],
            sdk_location=configs['sdk_location'],
            use_public_ips=configs['use_public_ips'],
            default_sdk_harness_log_level=configs['log_level']
        )
    else:
        with_attributes = True
        options = PipelineOptions(
            save_main_session=configs['save_main_session'],
            sdk_location=configs['sdk_location'],
            streaming=configs['streaming']
        )

    return options, entities, project, with_attributes, configs


def run():
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(IngestionPodOptions)
    try:
        options, entities, project, with_attributes, configs = create_pipeline_option_from_configs(pipeline_options, 'conf')

        pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    except OSError as ose:
        log_stacktrace(ose)
    except KeyError as ke:
        log_stacktrace(ke)

    else:
        schema_client = SchemaServiceClient()

        for entity in entities:
            try:
                entity_name, entity_info = list(entity.items())[0]
                # deduplication_attribute_id = entity_info['deduplicationAttributeId']
                topic = entity_info['topic']
                dlq_topic = entity_info['dlqTopic']
                schema_id = entity_info['schema_id']
                gcs_event_subscription = entity_info['gcsEventSubscription']
                source_bucket = entity_info['source_bucket']
                target_bucket = entity_info['target_bucket']
                target_project = entity_info['target_project']
                input_file_split_char = entity_info['input_file_split_char']
                input_file_split_char_entity_position = entity_info['input_file_split_char_entity_position']
                input_file_split_char_date_position = entity_info['input_file_split_char_date_position']

                schema_path = schema_client.schema_path(
                    project=project,
                    schema=schema_id
                )

            except IndexError as ie:
                log_stacktrace(ie)
            except KeyError as ke:
                log_stacktrace(ke)

            else:
                try:
                    """
                    Refs: 
                    1) https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-
                        using-pubsub-dataflow
                    """
                    avro_schema = \
                        schema_client.get_schema(
                            request={"name": schema_path}
                        )

                    # print(f"Got a schema:\n{schema}")
                    output = (pipeline |
                              "Read from PubSub event topic {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                                  subscription=f"projects/{project}/subscriptions/{gcs_event_subscription}",
                                  with_attributes=True if with_attributes else False,
                                  id_label="objectId" if with_attributes else None
                              )
                              | "Extract message data from PubSub message {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.Map(lambda message: extract_message_data(message, with_attributes))
                              | "Parse PubSub message event {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.Map(lambda message: json.loads(message))
                              | "Extract file path {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.Map(lambda message: message.get('name'))
                              | "Filter by subfolder {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.Filter(filter_subfolder, entity_name)
                              | "Filter message {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.Filter(filter_entity, entity_name, input_file_split_char, input_file_split_char_entity_position, input_file_split_char_date_position)
                              #| "Build GCS path {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              #beam.ParDo(ExtractFn(entity_name=entity_name, target_project_id=target_project))
                              | "Reshuffle {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.Reshuffle()
                              | "Decompress and copy file {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              beam.ParDo(CopyFile(
                                  source_bucket=source_bucket,
                                  file_path_source=entity_name+FILE_EXTENSION,
                                  destination_bucket=target_bucket,
                                  entity_name=entity_name,
                                  avro_schema=avro_schema,
                                  file_name=entity_name+FILE_EXTENSION,
                                  project_id=configs['project'],
                                  target_project_id=target_project))
                              .with_outputs("record")
                              #| "Read file message {}".format(entity_name) >>
                              #beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
                    )

                    records = (output.record | "Validating record {}".format(entity_name) >>
                    beam.ParDo(ValidateRecord(avro_schema=avro_schema, entity=entity_name))
                    .with_outputs("dlq", "valid")
                    )

                    encoded = (records.valid
                      | "Encode message to binary {}".format(entity_name) >> beam.ParDo(
                                 EncodeMessage(avro_schema=avro_schema))
                                 .with_outputs("encoded_record")
                    )

                    (encoded.encoded_record
                      | "Publish message to PubSub{}".format(entity_name) >> beam.ParDo(PublishToPubSubEncoded(f"projects/{configs['project']}/topics/{topic}"))
                    )

                    (records.dlq
                      | "Encode DLQ message to binary {}".format(entity_name) >> beam.Map(
                                 lambda message: json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'))
                      | "Publish DLQ message to PubSub{}".format(entity_name) >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(
                                 f"projects/{configs['project']}/topics/{dlq_topic}")
                    )


                except NotFound as nf:
                    logging.error(f"Schema not found in {schema_path}.")
                    log_stacktrace(nf)
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error("Something went wrong in the construction of the pipeline.")
                    log_stacktrace(e)

        pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

while utils file is:

```
import io
import json
import logging
import traceback
from abc import ABC
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Any
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import apache_beam as beam
import avro.schema as schema
import avro.errors
from apache_beam import pvalue
from avro.io import BinaryEncoder, DatumWriter
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import exceptions

""" ------------ CONSTANTS ------------------- """
FILE_EXTENSION = ".dat.gz"
""" ------------------------------- """


class EncodeMessage(beam.DoFn, ABC):

    def __init__(self, avro_schema, *unused_args, **unused_kwargs):
        super().__init__(*unused_args, **unused_kwargs)
        self.avro_schema = avro_schema
        self.schema_parsed = schema.parse(self.avro_schema.definition)

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        bout = io.BytesIO()
        #schema_parsed = schema.parse(self.avro_schema.definition)
        writer = DatumWriter(self.schema_parsed)
        encoder = BinaryEncoder(bout)

        try:
            writer.write(element, encoder)
        except avro.errors.IONotReadyException as ioe:
            logging.error(f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: {ioe}")

        data = bout.getvalue()
        yield pvalue.TaggedOutput("encoded_record", data)


class CopyFile(beam.DoFn, ABC):
    # https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/

    def __init__(self, source_bucket, file_path_source, destination_bucket, entity_name, avro_schema, file_name,
                 project_id, target_project_id, *unused_args, **unused_kwargs):

        super().__init__(*unused_args, **unused_kwargs)
        self.file_obj = io.BytesIO()
        self.storage_client = None
        self.storage_client_destination = None
        self.source_bucket = source_bucket
        self.file_path_source = file_path_source
        self.destination_bucket = destination_bucket
        self.entity_name = entity_name
        self.blob_copy = None
        # https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/generation_metageneration#using-ifgenerationmatch
        self.destination_generation_match_precondition = None

        self.avro_schema = avro_schema
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.file_path_suffix = None
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.target_project_id = target_project_id

    def setup(self):
        self.storage_client = storage.Client()
        self.storage_client_destination = storage.Client(project=self.target_project_id)
        self.file_obj = io.BytesIO()

    def process(self, file_path, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.file_name = file_path
        self.file_path_suffix = self.file_name.split('/')[-1]
        try:
            logging.info(f"Exporting file {file_path}")
            self.reading_file_from_bucket(file_path, self.file_path_suffix)
            logging.info(f"Exported file {file_path}")
            logging.info(f"Decompressing {file_path}")
            with gzip.open(filename=self.file_obj, mode='rb', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
                decompressed_data = f.read()
                for line in decompressed_data.splitlines():
                    record = self.parse_and_enrich(str_to_parse=line, separator='\x1f')
                    yield pvalue.TaggedOutput("record", record)
            logging.info(f"Decompressed {file_path}")
        except gzip.BadGzipFile:
            logging.error(f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: File {self.file_name} is not a valid gzipped file.")

    def parse_and_enrich(self, str_to_parse: str, separator: str) -> List[str]:
        """
        Parse the line, given a separator and enrich it by adding custom fields:
            1) load_dt
            2) file_name

        :param str_to_parse: Record of the processed file
        :param separator: Separator used to split the processed file
        :return: list
        """
        values = str_to_parse.split(separator)
        values[-1] = values[-1].strip()

        values.insert(0, str(datetime.now()))
        values.insert(1, self.file_name)

        return values

    def finish_bundle(self) -> None:
        if self.blob_copy:
            if self.blob_copy.exists():

                logging.info(f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: "
                             f"Moving input/{self.entity_name}/{self.file_path_suffix} to "
                             f"processed/{self.entity_name}/{self.file_path_suffix}")

                destination_bucket = self.storage_client.bucket(self.destination_bucket)

                try:
                    destination_bucket.copy_blob(self.blob_copy, destination_bucket,
                                                 f'processed/{self.entity_name}/{self.file_path_suffix}',
                                                 if_generation_match=self.destination_generation_match_precondition)

                    destination_bucket.delete_blob(f'input/{self.entity_name}/{self.file_path_suffix}')

                except exceptions.NotFound as nfe:
                    logging.error(f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: Destination bucket not found ! {nfe}")

                except exceptions.GoogleCloudError as gce:
                    logging.error(
                        f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: Something went wrong during the deletion of the blob. {gce}")

            else:
                logging.error(f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: \
                    No such object input/{self.entity_name}/{self.file_path_suffix}")

    def reading_file_from_bucket(self, file_path: str, file_path_suffix: str) -> None:
        """
        Download the file from the bucket into a BytesIO object.

        :param file_path: Path of the file to process
        :param file_path_suffix: Name of the file to process
        :return: None
       Refs:
        1) https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-copy-file?hl=it#storage_copy_file-python
        2) https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-stream-file-download?hl=it#storage_stream_file_download
           -python

       """
        source_bucket = self.storage_client.bucket(self.source_bucket)
        source_blob = source_bucket.blob(file_path)
        destination_bucket = self.storage_client_destination.bucket(self.destination_bucket)
        file_path_destination = f'input/{self.entity_name}/{file_path_suffix}'

        try:
            self.blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
                source_blob, destination_bucket, file_path_destination,
                if_generation_match=self.destination_generation_match_precondition
            )

            self.blob_copy.download_to_file(self.file_obj)
            # Rewind the stream to the beginning.
            self.file_obj.seek(0)

        except exceptions.NotFound as nfe:
            logging.error(f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: Destination bucket not found ! {nfe}")

        except exceptions.GoogleCloudError as gce:
            logging.error(
                f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: Something went wrong during the download of the file {self.file_name}!"
                f" {gce}")


class ValidateRecord(beam.DoFn, ABC):

    def __init__(self, avro_schema, entity, *unused_args, **unused_kwargs):
        super().__init__(*unused_args, **unused_kwargs)
        self.avro_schema = avro_schema
        self.entity = entity
        self.cleaned_schema = self.avro_schema.definition.replace('\n', '')
        self.avro_schema_json = json.loads(self.cleaned_schema)

    def process(self, record, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            #enriched_record = self.parse_and_enrich(str_to_parse=record, separator='\x1f')
            logging.debug(f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: Validating the following record => {record}")
            validated_record = self.validate_schema(input_to_validate=record)
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput("valid", validated_record)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(
                f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: Error while validating '{self.entity}' record against the schema: {e}")
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput("dlq", record)



    def validate_schema(self, input_to_validate: list[str]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        """
        Validate each line of the processed file against the Avro Schema and transform it in a dictionary type.

        :param input_to_validate: Record of the processed file
        :return: dict
        """
        const_str, const_bool = "string", "boolean"
        const_int, const_long, const_float, const_double = "int", "long", "float", "double"

        record_dict = {}

        if len(self.avro_schema_json['fields']) != len(input_to_validate):
            raise Exception(
                f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: The record's number of fields must be equal to the PubSub "
                f"Avro Schema's fields number."
                f"The number of Avro schema fields is {len(self.avro_schema_json['fields'])} "
                f"while file contains {len(input_to_validate)} fields"
            )

        for field in self.avro_schema_json['fields']:
            field_name = field['name']
            field_type = field['type']
            try:
                # Union type. (Used to represent nullable fields)
                if isinstance(field_type, list):

                    if field_type[0] == const_str or field_type[1] == const_str:
                        value = '' if input_to_validate[0] is None else input_to_validate[0]

                    elif (field_type[0] == const_int or field_type[1] == const_int) \
                            or (field_type[0] == const_long or field_type[1] == const_long):
                        value = None if (input_to_validate[0] is None or input_to_validate[0] == '') else \
                            int(input_to_validate[0])

                    elif field_type[0] == const_float or field_type[1] == const_float \
                            or field_type[0] == const_double or field_type[1] == const_double:
                        value = None if (input_to_validate[0] is None or input_to_validate[0] == '') else \
                            float(input_to_validate[0])

                    elif field_type[0] == const_bool or field_type[1] == const_bool:
                        value = None if input_to_validate[0] is None else input_to_validate[0].lower()

                    else:
                        raise ValueError(f"One of the following types in the union is not"
                                         f" supported: {field_type[0]} or {field_type[1]}")

                    input_to_validate.pop(0)
                    record_dict[field_name] = value

                else:
                    if field_type == const_str:
                        value = input_to_validate[0]

                    elif field_type == const_int or field_type == const_long:
                        value = int(input_to_validate[0])

                    elif field_type == const_float or field_type == const_double:
                        value = float(input_to_validate[0])

                    elif field_type == const_bool:
                        value = input_to_validate[0].lower() == 'true'

                    else:
                        raise ValueError(f"Type not supported: {field_type}")

                    input_to_validate.pop(0)
                    record_dict[field_name] = value

            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception(
                    f"{self.__class__.__qualname__}: Something went wrong during the validation of the record."
                    f" {e}. Sending {input_to_validate} to DLQ")

        return record_dict



def filter_subfolder(elem, entity_name: str) -> bool:
    """
    Check if the element path corresponds to an entity file uploaded in processed bucket subfolder.

    :param elem: Represents the file name
    :param entity_name: Name of the entity presents in the configuration file
    :return: bool
    """
    return elem.startswith(f"{entity_name}/processed/") and elem.endswith(FILE_EXTENSION)


def filter_entity(elem, entity_name: str, input_file_split_char: str, input_file_split_char_entity_position: int, input_file_split_char_date_position: int) -> bool:
    """
    Check if the element corresponds to an entity handled in the configuration file.

    :param elem: Represents the file name
    :param entity_name: Name of the entity presents in the configuration file
    :param input_file_split_char: Split string character used in input filename
    :param input_file_split_char_entity_position: Split index position used in input filename
    :param input_file_split_char_date_position: Split index position used in input filename
    :return: bool
    """

    try:
        return str(elem.split(input_file_split_char)[input_file_split_char_entity_position]).upper() == entity_name.upper() and datetime.strptime(str(elem.split(input_file_split_char)[input_file_split_char_date_position]), "%Y-%m-%d").date() >= datetime.now().date()
    except IndexError:
        logging.error(f"filter_entity: Something went wrong. Are you sure the used splitting character is valid ?"
                      f"Name of the file: '{elem}'. \n"
                      f"Character used to split: '{input_file_split_char}'")
        return False


def extract_message_data(pubsub_message, with_attributes) -> str:
    return pubsub_message.data.decode("utf-8") if with_attributes else pubsub_message.decode("utf-8")


def log_stacktrace(exception):
    tb_lines = traceback.format_exception(exception.__class__, exception, exception.__traceback__)
    tb_text = ''.join(tb_lines)

    logging.error(tb_text)
    raise


class ExtractFn(beam.DoFn, ABC):
    def __init__(self, entity_name, target_project_id, *unused_args, **unused_kwargs):
        super().__init__(*unused_args, **unused_kwargs)
        self.target_project_id = target_project_id
        self.entity_name = entity_name

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        #file_name = 'gs://' + self.target_project_id + "/" + element
        file_name = 'gs://test-lan-capt-chordiant-is-dev/processed/test/TEST:TEST:ENTITY:2024-02-29:14-43-00:0005040.dat.gz'
        logging.info('File: ' + file_name)
        yield file_name


class LogFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)
        yield element


class PublishToPubSubEncoded(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, topic_name):
        self.topic_name = topic_name

    def process(self, encoded_record):
        batch_settings = pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings(
            max_messages=1000
        )
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(batch_settings=batch_settings)
        # Publish the encoded record
        future = publisher.publish(topic=self.topic_name, data=encoded_record)
```

I've tried also the ReadAllFromText by beam but it is not recommended for streaming jobs.